# Prove that if every submodule of a free $R$-module is free, then $R$ is PID (using contrapositive)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals

I know that there are other answers to this question, but I want help with a specific approach. I want to use the contrapositive. $R$ is commutative and unital.
Here is what I have so far:

*Proof.* Suppose that $V$ is a free $R$-module. Recall also that a module is free if and only if it has a basis.
Recall that a principal ideal domain is an integral domain where all ideals are generated by one element.

We prove the contrapositive, that is, if $R$ is not a PID, then there exists a submodule of $V$ that is not free. Since $R$ is not a PID, that means that there exists an ideal $I$ of $R$ that is generated by at least two elements. Recall that $IV \leqslant V$ (it is a submodule). We claim that $IV$ is not a free module. It is sufficient to show that $IV$ does not have a basis. We denote
\begin{align*}
    IV &= \left\{\sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i : a_i\in I, v_i \in V, k \in \mathbb{N}\right\}\\
\end{align*}

I am stuck here. Is this an approach that will work or should I just try the direct proof?

Comment: “… there is an ideal $I$ of $R$ that is generated by at least two elements.” That’s true in a PID; you mean “nonprincipal ideal”.

Comment: Note: It is not sufficient to prove that every ideal can be generated by one element. We also have to show that $R$ has no zero divisors, i.e. is a PI**D**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: saying an ideal is “generated by at least two elements” does not, in and of itself, preclude the possibility that it it principal. I mean, $(2,3)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by at least two elements; it’s even a minimal generating set, as no proper subset generated the ideal! But of course $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID.

The key observation is this: in a domain, no two nonzero elements can be independent.

So, let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ that is not principal. We show it has no basis, even though $R$ (viewed as an $R$-module) is free. Indeed, let $X$ be a generating set for $I$. We prove that $X$ is not a basis.

Because $I$ is not principal, $X$ has more than one nonzero element. Let $a,b\in I$, $a\neq b$, both nonzero. Now define
$$r_x = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
b&\text{if }x=a,\\
-a&\text{if }x=b,\\
0&\text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.$$
and consider $\sum_{x\in X}r_xx$.

Comment: In the above, I see how this proves that $I$ does not have a basis, but does $I$ not having a basis mean that some submodule of $R$-module $V$ also does not have a basis? I am getting confused about the part where we view $R$ as an $R$-module rather than $V$

Comment: @RichardKYu: Every ring is a module over itself. And every ideal of a ring is a submodule of that module, and in particular a module. So the $R$-submodule I’m considering is $I$.

Comment: @RichardKYu You are trying to show that if $R$ is not a PID, then  there is a free module that has a nonfree submodule. The free module here is $R$; the nonfree submodule is $I$. $R$ is free over itself, with basis $1$.

Comment: @RichardKYu: Note that you do not need to prove that *every* free module has a submodule that is not free (that’s not true, since the trivial module is always free). What you need to prove is that there exists *at least one* free module that has *at least one* nonfree submodule. And the one I produced will do.